# Skip and Take not working for an IQueryable datasource

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a common method across all objects in my service layer named "GetBaseEntity". This basically has a definition of:

```cs
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetBaseEntity(bool includeNavigation = true, bool isAdmin = false)
{
    var objBase = _context.EntityName;

    if (isAdmin)
    {
        return objBase;
    }

    return objBase.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.IsDeleted == false);
}
```

This returns an IQueryable of type TEntity. I want to dynamically pass the pagination options in a method so I implemented it this way:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<EntityDto>> LoadResources(PagingOptions pagingOptions)
{
    var baseQuery = GetBaseEntity();

    if (pagingOptions != null)
    {
        baseQuery
            .Skip(pagingOptions.Page.Value * pagingOptions.Limit.Value)
            .Take(pagingOptions.Limit.Value);
    } 

    // I can actually return from this part but I just
    // set it to a variable to see how many rows the query will return
    var query = await baseQuery
        .ProjectTo<EntityDto>(_mappingConfiguration)
        .ToListAsync();

        return query;
}
```

However, the query still returns the whole set. My assumption is that the GetBaseEntity() just set-up the query but the execution applies on the LoadResourcesMethod where I applied the ToListAsync() in the LoadResources method.

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

1) not chaining the query ([IQueryable with Entity Framework - order, where, skip and take have no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432279/iqueryable-with-entity-framework-order-where-skip-and-take-have-no-effect))

```cs
if (pagingOptions != null) {
    baseQuery.Skip(pagingOptions.Page.Value * pagingOptions.Limit.Value);
    baseQuery.Take(pagingOptions.Limit.Value);
}
```

2) adding an "OrderBy" 
([WEB API IQueryable skip() take()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953932/web-api-iqueryable-skip-take))

```cs
    var query = await baseQuery
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .ProjectTo<EntityDto>(_mappingConfiguration)
    .ToListAsync();

    return query;
```

Any help on building a dynamic pagination from an IQueryable source?

Comment: Calling `Skip` and `Take` don't do anything except return the modified query, which you aren't capturing anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not updating your query in case of pagination. [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netcore-2.2) and [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-2.2) return a new `IEnumerable` as a result, instead of modifying the existing one in place.
So, you should replace this line:

```cs
baseQuery
   .Skip(pagingOptions.Page.Value * pagingOptions.Limit.Value)
   .Take(pagingOptions.Limit.Value);
```

with:

```cs
baseQuery = baseQuery
   .Skip(pagingOptions.Page.Value * pagingOptions.Limit.Value)
   .Take(pagingOptions.Limit.Value);
```

This way, you assign the new query value to the `baseQuery` and then when you enumerate it, it will return the expected entities.

Comment: Oh, I have thought chaining would be enough to update the base query by reference. Your solution worked and thanks for it!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it won't work if you misordered methods invocation

**Wrong:**

```
.Take(1) <-
.Skip(1)
```

**Correct:**

```
.Skip(1)
.Take(1) <-
```